# Curb around the perimeter of my exposed basement

Tags: construction

I want to remove this window and install a door in my exposed basement. There is a 5" high by 4" deep curb around the perimeter of the basement which I would need to remove, but I do not know if that is okay to remove, as I imagine it is built into the foundation for a reason. I do have a slider door on the same wall that must have been built in at the time the house was built in the mid-70s, that has no curb. Can you tell me if this is something I can remove?[image: Wall with curb]

Comment: This is a Question for the Home Improvement stack, not Woodworking. Don't do anything, the mods will migrate it for you.